# Changing str to int in Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
time = raw_input()
if "PM" in time:
    ls = time.split(":")
    int(ls[0])
    print type(ls[0])
```

I have a problem on Hackerearth which I was solving. But my code here doesn't change the str to int. **The output is**

```
<type 'str'>
```

I want to change the first element of the time to int so i can perform mathematical calculations on it. **Input it takes is**

```
6:05:08PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int()` returns the integer. The variable is not changed in-place.

Assign the result:

```
ls[0] = int(ls[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer = int(ls[0])
```

It cast str to an int and then u can use this Integer to do calculations

Answer (score 0):

`int(ls[0])` should do the trick for you, however, note that this is a very less safe approach.